# Is there a way to input just required numbers of characters in a c++ character array

Tags: c++, arrays, validation

I have to input and check character array in C++ using **bool** function. If it is more than 10 characters program must return false. If it is less than 10 characters prog must return true.
I have tried the following way but I am not getting desired result. PLZ help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
bool namefunc( char name[10] );
int main()
{
    char name[10];
    cin.getline(name,10);
    int print = namefunc(name);
    cout<<print;

}
bool namefunc( char name[10] ) {

    if (strlen(name)>10)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: strlen can never return >= 10 for that array, because one char will be the null terminator. cin.getline(name,10); will limit the number of bytes returned to 10, no matter how many you enter in the prompt.

Comment: @Michael slight correction: `strlen` can never return `>= 10` for that array *without dipping into Undefined Behavior*

Comment: @scohe001 Michael's right here. There can't be UB. `std::iostream::getline` will have stopped at 9 characters, terminated and set a fail bit in `cin`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use c-strings:

```
#include<cstring>
```

use C++ `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool namefunc(const std::string& name)
{
    return name.size() <= 10;
}

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cin.getline(name);
    bool print = namefunc(name);
    std::cout << print;

}
```

Comment: Dear One, I cannot change my function name and data types of parameters though.

Comment: Your original function is wrong, a `char[10]` array can't have more that 10 characters without Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @NadeemKhan you're checking in the wrong order. You can't check for buffer overflow after the buffer is overflowed. The program is already unstable at that point and cannot be trusted In this case the point is moot. `cin.getline(name,10);` cannot give you more than 9 characters (the tenth character is used by the null terminator). If the user tries to input more than 9 characters, `cin` will be placed in fail state and become unreadable until the error state is `clear`ed.